# Highlight project names in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

My solution has 17 projects. When navigating between them (generally all of the projects are expanded) I often get lost. Is there a way to highlight (mark) **all** project names in Solution Explorer?

Navigating between files isn't a problem - I'm using Resharper's navigation for that.

Comment: Have you tried `ctrl-;` to go to the search bar in the new Solution Explorer?

Comment: It doesn't do what I'm looking for. The search bar is meant for filtering (narrowing), I'm looking for navigation. 
Let's say I have a project named MyProject. If I type "MP", I get only the project's name with no files.

Comment: I don't think that feature exists, though `ctrl-;` and then typing part of the project you want to navigate to works pretty well, it isn't exactly what you're after. Navigate with `arrow-down` to the item you want to highlight. Then use `ctrl-arrow-left` to go back to the full Solution Explorer view.